# Stack two images to obtain a single image on Python

Tags: python, image-processing, stack

I have been trying to stack two images.

The end result will be used as the input to my convolutional neural network.

Now I tried to use `dstack`, I also tried to use `PIL` by importing `Image.blend` but I cannot seem to be arriving to my desired result.

I am asking if anyone has any other ideas which I can use would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include what you have tried in code.

Comment: you paste from pillow

Answer (score 0):

This could help you out.

```
from PIL import Image

image1 = Image.open("img1.jpg")
image2 = Image.open("img2.jpg")
image1 = image1.resize((224, 224))
image1_size = image1.size
image2_size = image2.size
new_image = Image.new('RGB',(2*image1_size[0], image1_size[1]), (250,250,250))
```

Comment: I modified the code the following way: `image1 = H
image2 = T_resized
image1 = np.resize(image1,(224, 224))
image1_size = image1.size
image2_size = image2.size
new_image = Image.new('RGB',(2*image1_size[0], image1_size[1]), (250,250,250))` However at the last line I am obtaining an error: 'int' object is not subscriptable [Sorry can't figure out how to do linebreaks]

Comment: It is because numpy array’s size method is different than PIL’s size method. If you use numpy, you should apply .shape method instead of .size. Size gives an integer that how much place the array occupies.

Answer (score 0):

Resize them so that they are the same size, and then use np.stack with axis=3 (if you are using multi-channel images. Else, use axis=2.

Or are you trying to combine them into one image? If so, how? Masking, adding subtracting?